# xcode not compiling changes

Tags: xcode, macos, compilation

I've implemented a Packet Tunnel Provider (which consist of a containing app and an extension)

Now I see that xcode ignore changes that I do at the extension - It looks like xcode compiles it (if i write something like "fefefe' at the code - it won't compile), but when I run the app, it's just the old version.

I tried all the following things:

- clean build
- restart
- deleting the .app and the build library
- I have no referance libraries at the project
- tried to archive

Nothing helps, and I don't know what else to do

Comment: kudos for a question that is tagged xcode that is actually an xcode question!

Comment: LOL :) gotta love xcode

Comment: And how his you solved it?

Comment: I did all the steps I listed above, and suddenly after I archived the app, it started working again